# Styles of fluid extractors

Tags: oil-change

Fluid extractors meant for changing engine oil come in two varieties.

One style has the pump inside the fluid reservoir. The extractor consists of a cylinder, with tubes and a handle at the top.

Another style has the pump outside the extractor proper. The extractor consists of *two* adjacent cylinders.

Is one style inherently superior to the other? Would it, for example, be harder to drain the neater looking first style because there are many more surfaces that the oil would cling to?

Comment: I think this question will draw a lot of opinion and won't get a proper answer, but we'll see.